# Question based on finding the area of canvas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The slant height of a conical tent made of canvas is $14/3$m. The radius of the tent is $2.5$m. The width of the canvas is $1.25$m. If the rate of canvas per metre is Rs. $33$ what is the total cost of canvas required?

I calculated the lateral surface area of cone which is $22/7\times2.5\times14/3\times$ and then multiplied the answer with the rate which is $33$ but my answer isn't correct. 
Correct answer is $968$.
 Does width play any role here? 
Please help me out guys

Comment: The cost of the per square meter is not $33$, but $33\cdot4/5$ instead so the final answer is $22/7\cdot5/2\cdot14/3\cdot4/5\cdot33=968$.

Comment: why 33*4/5. What is the role of width @MichaelHoppe

Comment: Well, if the cost $1\cdot1.25=5/4$ square meter is $33$, the how much does one square meter cost?

Answer (score 1):

Here we need to compare the lateral  area of Canvas and tent
So, $22/7*2.5*14/3 = (L) (1.25)$
$\Rightarrow L = 29.33$
Now, per length it's Rs. $33$.
Therefore for length $= 29.33 \times 33 =968$